# Add a custom text tooltip that differs from point to point in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am trying to develop a chart that displays a custom 'text' tooltip that I can set to change from point to point. Here is my code as of now:

```
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Winter 2007-2008',
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  9), 0.6 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 16), 0.6 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 28), 0.67],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  1), 0.81]
                ]
            }
```

Now this works as intended, but I am trying to add an extra bit of text that will appear in the tooltip when hovering over a point. This is my desired input for a data point (although I dont know if I will have to change it for my final product).

```
 [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 , 'custom tooltip1'],
 [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 , 'custom tooltip2'],
```

I would want the text displayed in a newline below the current tooltip:

[image: current tooltip]

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or can point me somewhere I can find some answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your data to be something like this:

```
data: [
   {x: Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 
    y: 0.7 ,
    customtooltip: 'custom tooltip1'},
   {x: Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 
    y: 0.7 ,
    customtooltip: 'custom tooltip2'}
]
```

Then in do a tooltip formatter function like this:

```
tooltip: {
     formatter: function() {
          var dt = new Date(this.x);
          var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
          var dtstr = dt.getDate()+". "+months[dt.getMonth()];
          var tooltip = '<b>'+this.series.name+'</b><br>'+dtstr+': '+this.y+' m<br>'+this.point.options.customtooltip;
          return tooltip;
     }
}
```

See how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks! It indeed does add the custom tooltip text, however now the X value in the tooltip is displayed as some other type of time format (I think...). For example, (1970, 10, 19) is displayed in the tooltip as 1404259200000. Do you know how I can fix this?